# python finding indexes of strings does not work

Tags: python, find

I have a list of filenames and a filename. Now I want to get the index.

I can check that an entry exists, does that match only for identical entries?

```
count = tfilename.count(filename)
if count > 0:
    print(f'{filename} is present in the list for {count} times.')
```

I can also get the index of the first

```
indexT = tfilename.index(filename)
```

However my search function always returns empty

```
def findMatches(s, l1):
    matched_indexes = []
    i = 0
    length = len(l1)

    while i < length:
        listElement = l1[i]
        if listElement.find(s) > 0:
            matched_indexes.append(i)
        i += 1
    return matched_indexes

indexesT = findMatches(filename, tfilename)
```

Now I do not have a solution for finding substrings in a list and returning an array with all indexes. It seems like a simple task but does not work.

Comment: It doesn't return "empty" it returns `None` because you didn't add a `return` statement.

Comment: The return value is in my code and returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The error was the missing = sign in the code at the comparison

```
def findMatches(s, l1):
    matched_indexes = []
    i = 0
    length = len(l1)

    while i < length:
        listElement = l1[i]
        if listElement.find(s) >= 0:
            matched_indexes.append(i)
        i += 1
        
    return matched_indexes
    
l1 = ['abc', 'bc', 'c']
i1 = findMatches('a', l1)
i2 = findMatches('b', l1)
i3 = findMatches('c', l1)
```

results in

```
[0]
[0,1]
[0,1,2]
```